# Manipulating data from a stored procedure by saving data into a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Problem: I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and I want to put constraints to the output so I only get relevant information.

I am using `Execute`. The way I see it I have two options:

1. save the result of the execution into a table, so I can use it for different purposes
2. put constraints to the variables in `Execute` so I only get the results I want

The first method is discussed here:
[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/insert-results-of-a-stored-procedure-into-a-temporary-table) .

My code is (due to company information I can't share the whole thing):

```
create table #mtable ( .... )

Insert into #mtable
    Execute [myProcedure]
```

The error:

> An INSERT EXEC statement cannot be nested.

I assume the error is because of the code in the stored procedure. How can I fix that problem without looking into the code for the stored procedure. Is there another way where I can save the content in a table?

My problem can also be solved by proposal #2. Is it possible for me to manipulate the output from the stored procedure with something like:

```
Execute [myProcedure] where variable1 > 100
```

Comment: By the error, `MyProcedure` uses `INSERT .. EXEC` itself, so you're out of luck. Your only remaining workaround if you can't change the procedure in any way (by making it a table-valued function, for example, which would really help) is to use `OPENQUERY`, but that has many caveats and pitfalls. I recommend reading [Erland Sommarskog's article on the matter](http://www.sommarskog.se/share_data.html). Bottom line: either write some client code to do it (not SQL) or crack open the stored procedure (adding the filtering to the stored procedure itself is the most efficient approach).

Comment: Why not pass the table name to the stored procedure and have it do the insert?

Comment: @JeroenMostert, can you suggest other ways to sovle my problem?

Comment: Petition Microsoft to allow nesting `INSERT ... EXEC` using a big bag of support money? That said, if you have that kind of money, getting a T-SQL developer who can rewrite things for you without nested `INSERT .. EXEC`s is probably more effective. There is no silver bullet or magic switch here -- you'll have to dig in and rewrite. You probably want to push search conditions down to the lowest level where possible anyway -- simply because it's more efficient. T-SQL is not a language designed for modularity and reuse.